# ¿Como mostrar un modal loading mientras se sube un archivo en asp.net c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Hola amigos espero se encuentren bien; espero me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema de antemano muchas gracias por su aporte.

Tengo un formulario donde subo un archivo y lo guardo en una carpeta en mi proyecto sin oprimir ningún botón como este ejemplo: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-File-without-clicking-Submit-Button-using-FileUpload-control-in-ASPNet.aspx

Sin mas, lo que trato de hacer es mostrar una popup con una imagen gif.

Mi problema es que esta si se muestra pero al hacer postback el botón la modal se cierra y lo que necesito es que se siga ejecutando ya que ejecuto código de servidor y javascript dentro de mi botón para mostrar los datos del archivo subido (mi archivo es un excel y despues de subirlo muestro su contenido en un jqxGrid).

Aquí mi código:

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
        {

        } 
 fuImportarArchivo.Attributes["onchange"] = "GuardarArchivo(this)";
```

Aquí el código del botón.

```
  protected void btnGuardar_archivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (fuImportarArchivo.HasFile)
        {

           string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fuImportarArchivo.FileName);
           string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fuImportarArchivo.FileName);

            if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {

                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Excel_Archivos/" + fileName);
                Session["fileLocation"] = fileLocation;
                fuImportarArchivo.SaveAs(fileLocation);

                lblMensaje.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(4, 180, 4);
                lblMensaje.Text = "El archivo se ha evaluado correctamente";

                //Aqui mando a ejecutar mi web Method
                string script = "<script type=text/javascript>obtener_datosExcel();</script>";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "obtener_datos", script, false);


            }
            else
            {
                lblMensaje.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                lblMensaje.Text = "Asegurese de haber selccionado un archivo Excel";

            }
           }
       }
```

Aquí mi código javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

        function GuardarArchivo(fileUpload) {
            if (fileUpload.value != '') {
                //Aqui muestro mi modal
                $('#Popup_cargando').modal('show');
                document.getElementById("<%=btnGuardar_archivo.ClientID %>").click();                            
               
            }
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacerlo mediante AJAX de forma asíncrona para que no se te recargue la página.
En vez de `document.getElementById("<%=btnGuardar_archivo.ClientID %>").click();` tienes que realizar aquí la llamada AJAX a una URL que te almacene el excel. Finalmente, en el `success` de AJAX ocultas el modal.